# iOS WatchKit app fails to install when running from Xcode - WCSession counterpart app not installed - how to fix?

Tags: xcode10, ios12, watchos-5

I'm looking at [this example of using watch connectivity by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app)

I've configured the app group and app identifiers, and the app compiles and runs on my phone, and a loading indicator appear on the watch. However, the **app never appears on the watch.**

The only message I get in the console is:

> WCSession counterpart app not installed

I see the app I'm trying to install in the list of available apps on the Apple Watch App> Available apps. It has "install" button. Tapping the install shows loading indicator on the watch, but the app still fails to appear on the watch.   I have another WatchOS app that I run from Xcode, and that one does appear on device, so I know it's possible to deploy app from Xcode

**How do I resolve WatchOS app failing to install from Xcode (WCSession counterpart app not installed)?**

Comment: This happened to me a couple of days ago - the Install loading indicator for the app in the phone's Watch app kept going to 100% and then back to zero. The traditional deleting the app on phone and watch, `Clean Build Folder` and Xcode restart sorted it. Welcome to watch debugging 

Comment: I noticed 2 possible causes: not calling the handler for the complication callbacks or renaming the app display name in the watchkit plist - the app name as displayed in the "available for install" list